# Using jest to test an Angular Library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-library

Trying to test an Angular 9 library with Jest, and I've installed the dependencies for Jest and Typescript within the local library `package.json` like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1"
  },
```

And also setup `jest.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src/"
  ],
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

However it looks as if jest is not running through the `ts-jest` transform as I'm getting errors like this:

````
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

    > 1 | import assertString from './util/assertString';
        | ^
      2 | import toString from './util/toString';```
````

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I'm converting ValidatorJS into a Typescript project using the Angular Package Format, and I forget to change the file name extension on the utilities from `.js` to `.ts`, hence Jest was complaining about the import statement.

In case anyone else wants to setup their project to do this type of thing I wrote up a few articles here:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/unit-testing-angular-with-jest-b65888ff33f6

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/unit-testing-your-angular-library-project-with-jest-42429a8716eb